# C++ Binary file read issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file

I was making a function to read a file containing some dumped data (sequence of 1 byte values). As the dumped values were 1 byte each, I read them as chars. I opened the file in binary mode, read the data as chars and did a casting into int (so I get the ascii codes). But the data read isn't correct (compared in a hex-editor). Here's my code:

```
int** read_data(char* filename, int** data, int& height, int& width)
{
    data=new int*[height];
    int row,col;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename,ios::binary|ios::in);
    if(!infile.good())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    char* ch= new char[width];
    for(row=0; row<height; row++)
    {
        data[row]=new int[width];
        infile.read(ch,width);
        for(col=0; col<width; col++)
        {
            data[row][col]=int(ch[col]);
            cout<<data[row][col]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    infile.close();
    return data;
}
```

Any ideas what might be wrong with this code?
My machine is windows, I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and the (exact) filename that i passed is:

```
"D:\\files\\output.dat"
```

**EDIT**: If I don't use unsigned char, the first 8 values, which are all 245, are read as -11.

Comment: Try reading into *unsigned* chars and converting to *unsigned* ints.

Comment: data should be allocated outside of this function.

Comment: @longbkit This is C++. Data shouldn’t be manually allocated at all.

Comment: @longbkit Outside of this function, I take care of 'data'. In this function, values are being copied into 'data' array. So, no problem with the array, I can assure you that.

Comment: Could you give us more details - what kind of incorrectness do you have?

Comment: @tyz I get wrong input values read from the input file... I printed the values of casted chars to int, and then used a hex-editor to view real file contents. As mentioned below, dumped values were near 245... I think I do need to take unsigned chars... But when I do so, I get another compilation error... infile.read() expects a char*, and not an unsigned char*

Comment: @Konrad Even with C++, for unknown size array you will have to use dynamic array and so must manually allocated.

Comment: @c0da  I see you allocate data inside the function, and then return this. So I mean please make sure it will be deleted somewhere outside. Even that, it's not recommended this way. Better allocate it outside and pass the pointer to this function.

Comment: @longbkit Nonsense. You should use a standard library container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you might have to use unsigned char and unsigned int to get correct results. In your code, the bytes you read are interpreted as signed values. I assume you did not intend that.

Comment: But a byte is a byte. The exact 8 bytes are copied into the 8 byte array. Then accessing the individual elements of the array isn't an issue when the dumped values were also integers.

Comment: If the dumped values are smaller than 127 or if the original values were also signed, you are right.

Comment: Dumped values were near 245... I think you all are right... I need to take unsigned chars... But when I do so, I get another compilation error... infile.read() expects a char*, and not an unsigned char*

Comment: @cOda: The problem is if your byte is 255, your char will be 255 or -1 depending on your platform. But if it's -1, it'll be promoted to the *integer* -1.

Comment: @cOda: yes, you have to cast either when you read, or leave the chars and cast later: `unsigned int value = (unsigned char)(c);`

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to cover in using of `char*` for `ch`. When you try to output it, all chars are printed until the first zero value.

Comment: That was some debugging info I had used for printing value on-screen. I edited the question. Check now.

Comment: this line of code does individual data allocation for the rows: data[row]=new int[width];

Answer (score 0):

A plain `char` can be either signed or unsigned, depending on the compiler. To get a consistent (and correct) result, you can cast the value to `unsigned char` before assigning to the `int`.

```
data[row][col]=static_cast<unsigned char>(ch[col]);
```